# Overriding URL paths sent to Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-analytics

In my web application, I have a path as `/search`.
I also have a cookie named `city` set as `CityA` or `CityB` depending on what the user selected previously. I have set up Google Analytics to monitor the Visitor Flow.

My question is, how can I override the path `/search` to show up as `/cityA/search` or `/cityB/search` in the Analytics Behavior Flow menu, depending on the cookie value?

PS. It is a Rails app and actually changing the URL is not feasible at this point, since I will then have to reconfigure my Routes.rb file and update links everywhere.

Edit:
I have to use ga.js. Moving to Universal Analytics(analytics.js) is beyond my control at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your analytics.js snippet you should see the following line:

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

You can pass an additional argument to the `send` method that overrides the page path. In your case it would look something like this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  page: 'cityA/search'
});
```

You'd have to add some Rails logic in your `.erb` file to adjust the page value based on the cookie, but that shouldn't be too much trouble.

For reference, here's some information on the send method and the arguments it accepts:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#send

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm stuck with the ga.js version of Analytics. I cannot update to Universal Analytics (it is not in my hand to update). Will this work for me?
Or should I do this:      `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/cityA/search']);`

Comment: Yeah, here's the documentation for the ga.js version: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview

Comment: You can also always open up the dev tools to the network tab and see what information is actually being sent to GA. I do this all the time to make sure everything is as I expect.